# Find multiples of a number in PHP

Tags: php, division, modulus

I want to find all muliples of a number in PHP.

I'm using something like this

```
if($count != 20 )
```

to work out if `$count` is not equal to 20.

But I also need this script to check if `$count` is not equal to 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160 etc.

Any ideas? I think i need to use the modulus symbol (`%`), but I don't know.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

```
if ($count % 20 != 0)
```

Answer (score 24):

```
if ($count % 20 != 0)
{
  // $count is not a multiple of 20
}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you don't want zero to be excluded:

```
if ($count % 20 != 0 || $count == 0)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like so:

```
if($count % 20 != 0)
```